# SharePoint data source issue

Tags: list, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have two sites of the same site colleciton and I want to use Data Source Library to make site A be able to use lists defined in site B. From site A, I am using "Connect to another library" to add site B. And from Data Source Library of site A, I can see lists defined in site B.

My question is how to use such lists in a page of site A?

I followed the guide here,

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191181033.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you would use Data View Web Parts (DVWPs).  (I think this question is hovering around in several other forms here and in the MSDN Forums.)

M.

Comment: Thanks, "where you would use Data View Web Parts" -- any more guides or documents about how to use Data View Web Parts to display list from another site?

Comment: There's info all over the Web on this.  I'd start with http://EndUserSharePoint.com.  I also have a lot of stuff on my blog at http://mdasblog.wordpress.com.